# Getting gcc to work with Xcode

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am at a place where I don't have the installation CD or the bandwidth to do a full Xcode install (It would take well over a day) to get gcc.  However I did install xcode and I notice in Developer/Xcodefiles/usr/bin/ that there is gcc. When I click on it, a terminal opens up and exits complaining no input file. Is there any way I can salvage this? man gcc says no manual entry for gcc.Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "no input file" is gcc's complaint when you don't give it anything to  do. So it appears to be, at least minimally, working.

Comment: @Mat So how do I pass in something, it shows itself as an exec file. Clicking on it opens the terminal and then the terminal shows no input file and logs out.

Comment: gcc is a command-line tool. You use a shell.

Comment: @mat so why does man gcc not work? Besides what does it mean for no input file.

Comment: It means that either the man pages are not installed, or not in your MANPATH. Please search around for basic usage of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only gcc on OS X go here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen users complain about this project in stackoverflow. I wanted to avoid the hassle. I already have gcc in my virtual box running fedora. I thought since Xcode and gcc shows up, I could do something about it and not install this from github.